# Concatenate champ name1

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table with champ: Letter1, Letter2, Letter3 ... until 6.

```
Structure of my table:  
TYPEID | BenefitsID | Letter1 | Coef1 | Letter2 | Letter3 | Coef3 | Letter4 | Coef4 | Letter5 | Coef5 | Letter6 | Coef6 |  Resultat
```

I want to make a select request in WHILE loop like this :

```
 @count =1;
    While (@count<7)
    begin
    @letter = **(select letter+@count from ....)**
    ..
    end
```

The result I want is to select the value of Letter1, Letter2... and Coef1, Coef2 ... and multiply them to insert them in champ Resultat

My question is how to select Letter1, Letter2, ... in one request. Will the bold request works? Or should I use something else?

I used SQL server 2008..

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results would help clarify what you want to do.

Comment: The requested result is not clear, ,please add a data sample

Comment: I edited my first post, is it clear now ?

Comment: Real data please including the requested result (in a table structure) for the given sample

Comment: Numerated columns are good indication for a bad design. Would you like to share your motivation?

Comment: Still not clear. You have 6 columns and you want to multiply then with different columns? Select Letter1 * Letter2 etc will not work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MySQL, do you want something like this?

```
select concat(letter, (@count := @count + 1)
from t cross join
     (select @count := 0) params
order by ??
limit 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, numerated columns are good indication for a bad design.
Being that said, dynamic SQL will answer your need.

```
declare @count  int = 1
       ,@stmt   nvarchar(max)

While (@count<7)
begin
    set @stmt = 'select Letter' + cast(@count as varchar(10))  + ' from mytable'
    exec sp_executesql @stmt
    set @count = @count + 1
end
```

Comment: I want my queries be like :

Comment: SELECT LETTER1 FROM 'mytable'  //// SELECT LETTER2 FROM 'mytable' //// SELECT LETTER3 FROM 'mytable' ... Is your code while do that ?

Comment: Check updatd answer

Comment: Thank you ! If I want to add a WHERE to my query, should I add too in sq_executesql ?

Comment: Concatenate it to the @stmt variable and don't forget a space before the `where`